# Email Date Conversion in Python

Tags: python, email, datetime-format, data-conversion, python-datetime

I am capturing the header of an Email to Email Date in the format below:

```
Fri, 27 Mar 2020 12:05:17 +0000 (UTC)
```

I need to transform to the format: **YYYY-MM-DD HH: MM**

I tried to use the `datetime.strptime` function but to no avail.

Can anyone help me with this? As I'm starting now in Python, I'm taking a beating!

Comment: Please share what you already tried.

Comment: To import `datetime.strptime()` you need to do `from datetime import datetime` before

Answer (score 1):

I would use [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) to convert your string to a datetime object, then use [strftime](https://strftime.org/) to output a string of the desired format.

```
import datetime
from dateutil import parser
x = parser.parse("Fri, 27 Mar 2020 12:05:17 +0000 (UTC)")
print(x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

the output should be

```
2020-03-27 12:05
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard library's [email](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) package provides tools to parse [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.html) format datetime strings.

```
from email.headerregistry import DateHeader
kwds = {}   # This dict is modified in-place
DateHeader.parse('Fri, 27 Mar 2020 12:05:17 +0000 (UTC)', kwds)
kwds['datetime']
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 27, 12, 5, 17, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

While [DateHeader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.headerregistry.html#email.headerregistry.DateHeader) is the modern tool for parsing date headers, the legacy<sup>*</sup> function [email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime) is easier to use

```
from email.utils import parsedate_to_datetime
parsedate_to_datetime('Fri, 27 Mar 2020 12:05:17 +0000 (UTC)')
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 27, 12, 5, 17, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

<sup>*</sup>While to the docs list the `utils` module under the legacy API heading, parsedate_to_datetime is used [internally](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb852266b77ffeeb09a42847c907829eec6d5cb5/Lib/email/headerregistry.py#L306) by `DateHeader` to parse datetime strings, so it probably isn't going away any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

A custom implementation without using the `datetime` library if you don't want that dependency.

```
date_given = "Fri, 27 Mar 2020 12:05:17 +0000 (UTC)"

month ={'Jan':'01','Feb':'02','Mar':'03','Apr':'04','May':'05','Jun':'06','Jul':'07','Aug':'08','Sep':'09','Oct':'10','Nov':'11','Dec':'12'}

_,d,m,y,t,_,_ = date_given.split(' ')

print(str(y)+"-"+str(month[m])+'-'+str(d)+' '+str(t[:-3]))
```

Would give you `2020-03-27 12:05`